# MDM programming in iOS

Tags: ios, mdm

I am new at MDM programming for iOS devices. I have a licenced enterprise developer account. From where should i start programming? I have my own https server and i want to implement some command from my server to the device. Is it possible through MDM or not? please help me on that

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "too broad" because judging by your question I think you're lacking a huge amount of information about how MDM works and what's involved in setting it up. I'd encourage you to read as much of Apple's MDM documentation as you can, and once you've done that you'll probably be able to answer this question yourself. The short answer, though, is that server->device communication with or without MDM is generally done via push notifications.

Comment: Thank u Caleb. I want to install an application on device remotely from our https server. We have implemented that in android. In android such sdk's are available. But don't know about sdk in iOS. We have our own server. So  i want to connect that server.

Comment: It's certainly possible to install apps remotely via MDM once the device is enrolled, but it's not so much a programming problem as a system administration issue. You might have better luck asking on [sf].

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully implemented mdm demo project from https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server

Comment: Did you really? It seems like you only forked another project and no commit seems to be from you.